# Abstract Classes and virtual methods problems: cannot declare variable ‘list’ to be of abstract type ‘aStack<int>’ aStack<int> list(5)

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Hi i am trying to implement an array based stack (in c++) but i have been stuck in it for a while. whenever i try to make an object in my source file, compiler generates the error "cannot declare variable ‘list’ to be of abstract type ‘aStack’
   aStack list(5);" even though i aStack class is inheriting from ADT abs_stack. here's my code

```
enter code here

    // question #1. 
    // ADT for stack.
    template <class type> 
    class abs_stack {
    public:
    virtual void initialize_stack() = 0; // starts the stack.  
    virtual bool isEmpty() = 0; // checks whether stack is empty or not.
    virtual bool isFull() = 0; // checks whether stack is full or not. 
    virtual void push(type n) = 0; // 
    virtual void pop() = 0; 
    virtual type top() = 0; 
    };

    // declaring array based stack. 
    template <typename t> 
    //template <typename E> 
   // class AStack: public Stack<E>
   class aStack : public abs_stack<t> {
    private:
    t *grid; // stack. 
    int max_stack_size; 
    int top_element; // points to the top of the stack.  
    void stack_copy(aStack<t> &copy); // used in copy contructor. 
    public: 
    aStack(int size); // paratmeterized constructor.
    ~aStack(); // destructor. 
    aStack(const aStack <t> &); // copy constructor. 
    const aStack<t> & operator = 
    (const aStack<t> &originalStack); // overloaded assignment operator. 
    //------------------------------------->
    bool isEmpty() const; 
    bool isFull() const; 
    void pop(); 
    void push(const t &newElem); 
    t top() const; 
    void initialize_stack(); 
     };

enter code here

    #ifndef H_stack
    #define H_Stack

    #include <iostream>
    #include <cassert>
    #include "stack.h"
    using namespace std;

    // stack methods' implementation.

    template <class x> const aStack<x>& aStack<x>::operator=
                                (const aStack<x>& otherStack)
    {
    if (this != &otherStack) //avoid self-copy
    copyStack(otherStack);
    return *this;
    }//   end of overloaded assignment operator. 

    template <typename x> 
    void aStack<x> :: pop() {

    if (!isEmpty()) {
    top_element--; // decreases the position # of the top element. 
    }
    else {
    cout << "Error! Stack is already. Cannot remove anything." << endl; 
    }
    } // end of pop() 

    template <typename x>
    void aStack<x> :: push(const x &newElem) {
    if (!isFull()) {
    grid[top_element] = newElem; // places new element on the top
    top_element++;
    }
   else {
    cout << "No space available." << endl; 
    }
    } // end of push

    template <typename x> 
    x aStack<x> :: top() const {
    assert(top_element != 0); // checks whether stack exists or not. 
    return grid[top_element - 1]; 
    } 

    template <typename x> 
    void aStack<x>::initialize_stack() {
    top_element = 0; 
    } 

    template <typename x>
    bool aStack<x> :: isEmpty() const {
    return (max_stack_size == 0);
    }

    template <typename x> 
    bool aStack<x> :: isFull() const {
    return (top_element == max_stack_size);
    }

    template <typename x>
    aStack<x> :: aStack(int size) {
    if ( size <= 0) {
    cout << "Error! Stack size can" << 
    " never be lesser than/equal to 0." <<   endl
    << "Generating stack of size 10" << endl; 
    max_stack_size = 10; 
    } 
    else {
    max_stack_size = size; 
    }
    top_element = 0; 
    grid = new x[max_stack_size];
    } // end of parameterized contructor. 

    template <typename x> 
    aStack<x> :: ~aStack() {
    delete []grid; 
    grid = NULL; 
    max_stack_size = 0; 
    } // end of destructor. 

    template <typename x> 
    aStack<x> :: aStack(const aStack<x> &firstStack) {
    grid = NULL;
    stack_copy(firstStack); 
    } // end of copy contructor. 

    template <typename x> 
    void aStack<x> :: stack_copy(aStack<x> &copy) {
    delete []grid; 
    grid = NULL; 
    max_stack_size = copy.max_stack.size; 
    top_element = copy.top.element; 
    grid = new x[max_stack_size]; 
    // generating deep copy of the original stack. 
    for (int i =0; i < max_stack_size; i ++)
    grid[i] = copy.grid[i]; 
   }    // end of stack copy.
   #endif

   #include <iostream>
   #include "stack.h"
   using namespace std; 
   //--------- source file-->
   int main() {
   aStack<int> list(5);
   return 0;

   }
```

Comment: Watch out for those `const`s.

Comment: you don't override the right abstract functions (the signatures differ -  like const). If you have c++11 available add `override` to each function which should override and you see which ones those are.

Comment: can you explain it with depth?

Answer (score 1):

The error implies that your class aStack is an abstract class, i.e. has at least one pure virtual method and therefore cannot be instantiated. That means that some of your aStack methods failed to participate in virtual overriding as a result of signature mismatch.

Notice that cv-qualifiers and ref-qualifires affect the parameter type and change the signature:

```
void f(int x)
void f(const int& x)
```

are considered different functions. Same goes for member functions cv-qualifiers, so only `pop` and `initialize_stack` retain original signature in your code.